# AFNetworking 3.0 migration

Tags: ios, migration, afnetworking, nsurlcredential, afnetworking-3

Now I am using `AFNetworking 2.0`, I want to migrate it to `AFNetworking 3.0`. I've added files to the project, it shows many errors. I've checked the [migration guide](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-3.0-Migration-Guide). My doubt is how to set `NSURLCredential` to the login request url in `AFNetworking 3.0.4`. Now I am using,

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
if ([url rangeOfString:NSLoginUrl].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"userName" password:@"password" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
        [operation setCredential:credential];
    }
```

But `AFNetworking 3` not supports `AFHTTPRequestOperation` and
`AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you have to replace AFHTTPRequestOperation to AFHTTPSessionManager

then AFNetworking 3.0 exposes all of the authentication callbacks from NSURLSession, you can set any header you would like through AFURLRequestSerialization.